# Riak set timeout for individual keys

Tags: python, riak

What i would like to do is set a timeout for individual keys in riak
I know that you can set a timeout on using bitcask but if im not mistaken that is only to the buckets
i have a method where i could implement the timeout functionality manually but that would involve altering the metadata for that key

```
import riak

client = riak.RiakClient() 
bucket = client.bucket('somebucket')
key = bucket.get('somekey')
old_meta = key.get_metadata()
old_meta['new_key'] = 'new_value'
key.set_metadata(old_meta).store()
```

either the metadata does not update or it does not show immediately or am i missing something here .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary contains one entry for each type of metadata (keys can be found [here](https://github.com/basho/riak-python-client/blob/1.5.2/riak/metadata.py)). User metadata can therefore be set the following way:

```
client = riak.RiakClient(port=10018)
bucket = client.bucket('somebucket')
key = bucket.get('somekey')
old_meta = key.get_metadata()
old_meta['usermeta'] = {'new_key': 'new_value'}
key.set_metadata(old_meta).store()
```